# How to create a view with INSERT rule RETURNING a value - without INSERT in the rule definition

Tags: postgresql

I have the following simplified testcase:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id serial PRIMARY KEY, data varchar);

CREATE VIEW test_v AS SELECT * from test;

CREATE FUNCTION insert_test_fn(in_data varchar) RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE 
my_id integer;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (in_data)RETURNING id INTO my_id;
-- do things with my_id
RETURN my_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE RULE _INSERT AS
ON INSERT TO test_v DO INSTEAD
SELECT insert_test_fn(new.data);

INSERT INTO test_v (data) VALUES ('testval');

-- I would like to do this:
-- INSERT INTO test_v (data) VALUES ('testval') RETURNING id;
```

I have some client code which issues the statement

`INSERT INTO test_v (data) VALUES ('testval') RETURNING id;`.

This used to insert into test (`ON INSERT TO test_v DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO test ... RETURNING...`).

Now I need to change part of the behavior and instead of inserting directly into test, I want to call a function where this is done. (Parts of the data to be inserted will have to be calculated first).
Is there a way to define the `_INSERT` rule so that it still works when called with a RETURNING clause? This would allow me to leave the client code unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

That will work just fine, but it is unnecessarily complicated:

- You can directly insert into the view if its definition is as simple as that. But I assume that your actual case is more complicated.
- You don't need the function, you can directly put `INSERT INTO test ...` in the rule definition.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the case is more complicated and the function does more than just inserting. I autogenerate UI components like crud editors from database views metadata, that's why I would prefer to keep the view as an interface instead of calling the function directly from my application code. I can still make it a special case in the application and get the insert id by curval of the sequence.

Comment: Anyway, there is no problem with your approach.